# Fastest/ most efficient way to trigger an if statement if specific numbers are met

Tags: python

There are multiple ways to do this, but I'm looking for the fastest/ most efficient way.

I've got a counter, starting at 0, which increments every time an event triggers and goes up to 1000.
If the counter gets to 101, 201, 301, 401, 501, 601, 701, 801 or 901, something needs to happen.

Most simple way:

```
        if counter == 101:
            Do something
        if counter == 201:
            Do something
        if counter == 301:
            Do something
        if counter == 401:
            Do something
        #etc .......
```

We could make it more efficient by the following:

```
    if counter < 501:
        if counter == 101:
            Do something
        if counter == 201:
            Do something
        #etc .......
    if counter >= 501:
        if counter == 501:
            Do something
        if counter == 601:
            Do something
        #etc .......
```

Or even putting it in a loop in order to add a break:

```
for i in range (1):
    if counter < 501:
        if counter == 101:
            Do something
            break
        if counter == 201:
            Do something
            break
        #etc .......
    if counter >= 501
        if counter == 501:
            Do something
            break
        if counter == 601:
            Do something
            break
        if counter == 701:
            Do something
        #etc .......
```

BUT, there problem is that it's always going to trigger when the counter is in between the numbers (1, 2, 3, 102, 105, 106, 450, 459, 891, etc).

Another way I was thinking of was as follows:

```
if (counter == 101) OR (counter == 201) OR (counter == 301): #etc
    Do something according to number
```

But that's basically the same as having a bunch of if statements like the first example.

Lastly, I was thinking about it only triggering if the counter = like x01 (so x can be any number followed by 01).

```
for i in (0):
if "01" in str(counter):
    if counter == 101:
        do something
        break
    if counter == 201: 
        do something
        break
```

Wondering what you guys think

*EDIT: some are asking what "do something" is. It's simply changing a variable. So if counter = 101 -> var = "hello", if counter = 201 -> var = "bye", etc..

Comment: Are these `do somethings` functions?

Comment: I think this question heavily depends on what `do something` actually does. You may be better using the modulo-operator, if `do something` is something generic like adding `counter // 100` to something.

Comment: I'm not sure about the performances, but a way could be to have a dict with `int` keys containing `lambdas` for the logic, and then in your code do something like `your_dict.get(counter, lambda: None)()`

Comment: Another approach is to define function which are executed when a value is found.  Then, create a `dict` with the numeric value as the key, and the function as the value.

Comment: Are all the "do something" the same thing?

Comment: I've added a comment below. The do something are all the samen, simply changing a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the initial question the response from gchapuis would have been good. Now, since you actually only want to set a variable value, you can keep the dictionary approach but remove the "callable" idea. With this in mind, you could do the following:

```py
MAPPINGS = {
    101: "hello",
    201: "bye"
}

# later in your code

var = MAPPINGS.get(counter, var)  # give var as default, so it's unchanged if the counter value is not in the dict
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a dictionary containing all the values that need to trigger an action as key and a function as value.

Example:

```
mydict[101] = my_function
```

and then do:

```
if counter in mydict:
    mydict[counter](...)
```

Comment: Or perhaps `mydict.get(101)()`. This alleviates the `if`.

Comment: Could work, but you'd have an if as well to test the result of get

Comment: or you do `mydict.get(101, lambda: None)()`, this way you just execute a noop function if it's not there

Comment: @jkoestinger That's quite elegant!

Comment: @S3DEV `None` is far from the same as `lambda: None`.

Comment: @S3DEV but here it returns a lambda that does `None`, not just `None`

Comment: @jkoestinger - My apologies, I see your point now.  Nice one.

Comment: @jkoestinger how would the rest play out then? `mydict.get(101, lambda: None)() do something` or `mydict.get(101, lambda: None)() mydict.get(201, lambda: None)()`

Comment: No, just `mydict.get(counter, lambda: None)()`, but according to you edit, you can simplify it even further, I'll create a new answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the most elegant way I could think of, not necessarily more efficient though.

```
for i in range(1000):
    if i % 100 == 1:
        # do something
```